# Unknown property 'SObject. - Why can't I display the object?

Tags: sobject

I am somewhat of noob to the Visualforce side of SalesForce. For the life of me I can't get this code to work.

As you can see from the controller code there are two SoQL statements. Both have been tested in the SoQL editor and return results. The one that is commented out is the one that I really want to use. The one that is running is a simpler test query.

Can you guys tell me what is wrong with my code? Why am I having a hard time calling the contents of the object?

Here is my controller.

```
public with sharing class locationInformation {

  // Here we are generating the list of sites

  public List<sObject> Records {get; set;}       

  public locationInformation(){  

  Records = [SELECT puLocation__r.Name FROM Child_Consent_Form__c GROUP BY puLocation__r.Name];

//Records = [SELECT puLocation__r.Name, puLocation__r.Milk_Location__c, puLocation__r.notes__c, COUNT(Name) from Child_Consent_Form__c GROUP BY puLocation__r.Name, puLocation__r.Milk_Location__c, puLocation__r.notes__c ];  


  }
}
```

Here is my VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="locationInformation"> 
    <apex:pageBlock title="Location Food Distrabution Information">     

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Records}" var="Record"> 

            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!Record.puLocation__r.Name}"/>
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Notes</apex:facet> 
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column >     
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Limit 6 Bags/Bin</apex:facet> 
                7/55
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Locattion Type</apex:facet>        
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Number of Kids</apex:facet>                
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Milk</apex:facet> 
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Milk #</apex:facet> 
            </apex:column> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock>   
</apex:page>
```

I keep on getting the error

> Unknown property '`SObject.puLocation__r`'
>   Error is in expression '`{!Record.puLocation__r.Name}`' in component `<apex:outputText>` in page `food_distribution_manager`**

I have been reading and reading but am not getting anywhere. Any help would be aprreciated.

Comment: How did you get this to compile? Trying to run a very similar query gets me an `Illegal assignment from List<AggregateResult> to List<sObject>` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an AggregateResult query, you'll need to use Dynamic Visualforce to access the individual members. Also, I strongly advise using aliases in your query. Here's the revised code.

## Apex Code

```
// Provide an Alias to the field
Records = [SELECT puLocation__r.Name LocationName FROM Child_Consent_Form__c GROUP BY puLocation__r.Name];
```

## Visualforce

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Record['LocationName']}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you're seeing points to the issue that you don't have the correct type declared for `Records` in your controller.

If you're declaring `public List<sObject> Records`, that won't work for two reasons: (1), `sObject` has no property `puLocation__r`, since that's a property of your custom sObject, and (2), SOQL aggregate queries (`COUNT()` is an aggregate function) do not return sObjects - [they return `List<AggregateResult>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm).

You're going to need to restructure your query and decide how you want to store your results to get the types right before the Visualforce will compile. You may want to query from the parent level and use a subquery to get your count details, rather than querying up from the child level as you do here.

Comment: Except for pure COUNT() queries, AggregateResult queries can be aliased into a generic SObject. I wouldn't recommend it, but it's not strictly forbidden.

Comment: I know that I have some reading to do on this but could you point me in the right direction on how to get a subquery result on this VisualForce page for something like this?

SELECT puLocationr.Milk_Locationc FROM Child_Consent_Form__c WHERE Allergies_Typesc INCLUDES ('Dairy-free')

Comment: Hi @JimmyD, I don't know your data model or objective well enough to make a concrete commendation. You may find [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm) documentation useful. Generally speaking, you can do `SELECT Name, (SELECT Id FROM Child_Objects__r) FROM Parent_Object__c WHERE...`, and then in Visualforce obtain the count with {! parent_object.Child_Objects__r.size }

Comment: David, thank you for the help. It took me a few tries to understand it but once I did I was able to get one of the numbers that I was looking for. A+

Comment: David thank you for your help. I believe that I am making progress. it looks like I have to build a method that goes through my query, gets the variables, does a query on the site and gets the number of diary_free kids and apply that to a custom object. Then I would use that custom object, that is just a list of the site variables, to populate the VF page. The problem that I am having, and am asking you for help with, is what object should I use?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow your question. It sounds like you are interested in building an Apex wrapper class to store data that you've processed. That's distinct from a custom object and it's a common Visualforce design pattern.